# Обязательный слеш в конце URL (mod_rewrite)

Tags: url, .htaccess, mod_rewrite

На сайте используется ЧПУ, все запросы передаются в index.php. На данный момент в htaccess присутствуют следующие записи:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Ничего мудреного, потому и работает нормально. Но есть маленькая проблема - обязательное присутствие слеша в конце URL. Сами URL только двух типов : http://site.ru/part_1/part_2/ (*слеш в конце нужен*) и http://site.ru/part_1/part_2/?param=something (*слеш, понятное дело, не нужен*). В первом случае, если URL вводился, скажем, пользователем вручную и без слеша в конце, его надо дописывать.
Конечно могу сделать проверки средствами PHP уже при обработке запроса, но хотелось бы это как-то очеловечить. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я реализовал на `PHP`.

```
$exp = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if ( mb_substr($exp[0], -1) != '/' ) {
  header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
  header('Location: ' . $exp[0] . '/' . (!empty($exp[1]) ? '?' . $exp[1] : ''));
  exit();
}
```

Comment: Да, наверно это вариант, т.к. могу предположить, что правило mod_rewrite будет делать практически то же самое. Если это так, то возможно, что и заморачиваться не стоит с htaccess

Answer (score 1):

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.html$
 RewriteRule (.+) $1/ [R=301,L]
```