# Как добавить слэш в конце URL

Tags: php

пробовал все варианты что нашел в google, но как не крути работают оба варианта. Мне нужнo чтобы все ссылки имели слэш в конце.

Comment: через `mod_rewrite` пробовали? Вот тут наверное то, что нужно: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/81391

Comment: пробовал несколько вариантов, и если раньше ссылка была так:
http://site.ru/statistics

что сейчас стало так:
http://site.ru/index.php/?component=statistics

удалил то что добавил, но обратный вид не появляется.

Comment: возможно, чтобы вернуть прежний вид, нужно почистить серверный кэш

Answer (score 1):

Я использую следующий вариант, в .htaccess

```
# Редирект для категорий (чтобы в конце URL был /)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.xml$
RewriteRule (.*+) $1/ [R=301,L]
```